# Angularjs edit and save

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

If been working on this form, that can change the name and mail of the item.
  But when I looked at this link https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#services , I saw I made some mistakes in the style but now it doesn't work anymore.

I actually really don't know why. It shows the `{{vm.name}}` and `{{vm.email}}` but not the name, also It doesn't hide the input and the buttons who show up when you click on the edit button.

this is the link from plunker https://embed.plnkr.co/yqUsSkwNBPBfOQS5jm5l/ .

```js
angular
    .module("form",[])
    .controller("LocationFormCtrl", LocationFormCtrl);
    
    function LocationFormCtrl(){
      var vm = this;
      
      vm.name = 'henk';
      vm.mail = 'gmail';
      vm.editorEnabled = false;
      
      var service = {
        name: name,
        mail : mail,
        enableEditor : enableEditor,
        editorEnabled: editorEnabled,
        disableEditor: disableEditor,
        save: save
      };
      
      return service;
      
      function enableEditor(){
        vm.editorEnabled = true;
        vm.editName = vm.name;
        vm.editMail = vm.email;
      }
      
      function save(){
        vm.name = vm.editName;
        vm.email = vm.editMail;
        disableEditor();
      }
      
      function disableEditor(){
        vm.editorEnabled = false;
      }
      
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="form" ng-controller="LocationFormCtrl">
    
    <div ng-hide="editorEnabled">
      {{ vm.name }}
      {{ vm.email }}
        <div ng-click="enableEditor()" style="border-radius:50%; background-color:black; height:35px; width:35px;">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white;margin-left:11px; margin-top:10px;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div ng-show="editorEnabled">
      <label>Name:</label>
         <input type="text" ng-model="vm.editName" ng-show="editorEnabled">
        <br><br>
      <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.editMail" ng-show="editorEnabled">
      <div ng-click="save()" style="border-radius:50%; background-color:black; height:35px;width:35px;"  >
        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white; margin-left:11px; margin-top:10px;"></i>
      </div>
      <div ng-click="disableEditor()" style="border-radius:50%; background-color:black;height:35px; width:35px;">
        <i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white; margin-left:11px; margin-top:10px;"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What angular version are you using? I see ng-click which only exists in angularjs and your plunker uses angularjs, too . But the github repo is about angular2? Is it possible that you unwittingly mixed both versions?

Comment: As far as I know I am using angularjs, but if it's mixed then I made a mistake.

Comment: The broken url  linked to johnpapa/angular, which is about angular 2. The fixed url links to the angularjs style guide, so you used the correct one  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Either you use `this` syntax of angular controller to avoid `$scope`, or just use `$scope`.

I corrected your [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NzEz2UWAzRVtX7EfTUNo?p=preview), you have to use `as` syntax in `html view` and bind all data to `this` object in controller.
Please notice below points in plunker :

1. `ng-controller="LocationFormCtrl as vm"`
2. In html bind everything to `vm`, like `ng-click="vm.save()"`.
3. In controller bind everything to `this`, or its alias.. like `vm.enableEditor = function (){/\\`

and If you want to do it with `$scope` way, then see this [$sope Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3SlWnTIrgzfEqOIg4qbv?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. I have another question. How does it work with ng-click, it is changed to "ng-click="vm.save()". Only the buttons doesn't responds, when I click on the button.

Comment: @A.Berg : ng-show property `editorEnabled` also need to bind to `vm` then it will work. See this updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NzEz2UWAzRVtX7EfTUNo?p=preview). See console when save clicked.

Answer (score 0):

its because the reference was taken of controller in ng-controller as you can see,
its john papa Structure.

For more information you can check.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide